# Android Spell Checker not switching to different language

Tags: android, locale, spell-checking, spelling, android-spellcheck

I'm having issues with default android spell checker: it doesn't want to switch to a different language. Instead it uses default system language for spell check.

Spell Checker works with default language, but when I change Locale to a different language it does not give me corrected words, but when I change language of the system Spell Checking works fine.

here is my code:

```
   TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);

    Locale locale = new Locale("fr"); //whatever language
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    Resources res = ctx.getResources();
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());

    spellChecherSession = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, locale, this, true);
```

I read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/TextServicesManager.html) but I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

I've tried modifying locale and config, from multiple answers here, but it didn't work for me.

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks.